# <hr> tag of height 1px or 0.1rem rendering differently

Tags: html, css, tags

hr tag of 0.1rem (1px) height have different thickness. This could be fixed by using border-top property instead of height. But i need to implement a gradient color to tag which is possible only through background-image so i have to use height i guess.
https://codepen.io/TitaniumGT/pen/JjpLpGj
The problem has been duplicated in the codepen but the border-top fix doesn't work here and creates same issue which occurs when height is used.
It seems to happen at lines of even nos.

```
 hr {
  border: 0;
}
.line {
  height: 0.1rem;
  // border-top: 0.1rem solid;
  background-color: $color-primary-dark;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

Can somebody help me with this. If no solution is there any way to add gradients to borders?

Comment: It's easier for us to help if you include a runnable snippet in your question which demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, are you certain that using border instead of height always gives a consistent look?

Comment: I have added the snippet. Yes the border-top code worked in my code but doesn't work in the codepen.

Comment: I had to zoom to see the problem. At different zoom levels different lines look thicker/thinner. I think you are bumping up an edge effect problem. The system has to work out how to map CSS pixels into screen pixels (several screen pixels are used per CSS pixel on modern screens) and, similar to a rounding error, when it has to place things on fractional borders sometimes extra screen pixels get 'left behind'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this work for me

```
hr{
border-width: 5px; 
border-image: linear-gradient(to right,white,black,white) 1;
}
```

[image]

Note: 1 in border-image stretched linear-gradient to all width of line

Comment: Thank you for this. This will do.